# window.history.pushState function reloads the page when used

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

i am trying to go from page to page without reloading, i read on other questions that i can use

```
    window.history.pushState()
```

to not reload the page, but it is still reloading the page.

i also tried using this function but kept giving me a syntax error

```
  function changeurl(url, title) {
   var new_url = '/' + url;
   window.history.pushState('data', 'Title', new_url);
   document.title = title;
    }
```

the syntax error occurs and it reads: "unexpected token ,"

here is an example of my HTML:

```
 <a class="ac" href=""  onclick="window.history.pushState('data', 'Title', 'index?a=recieved');"></a></td>
        <li>

         <a class="" href="index?b=favorites" onclick=""></a></td>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a class="" href="index?a=sent" onclick=""></a></td>
        </li>
```

what can i do to get my pages not to reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **href="javascript:void(0)"** in tag a

```
<a class="ac" href="javascript:void(0)"  
onclick="window.history.pushState('data', 'Title', 'index?a=recieved');">
Link
</a>
```

Comment: good solution, now it actually changes the url without reloading, but the php side of the code is not executing

Comment: so it seems like it isnt really going to a different page only the url is changing

Comment: To run the php code it is necessary to use AJAX.

Changing the browser url does not reflect on the page.

You will have to make an AJAX request in the url of your PHP action and change the html of your page. 

This is not the best practice. In complex cases I would use VueJS, AngularJS, React.

Comment: so then, there is no way to go to another page without refresh? (without using ajax) because many answers were as simple as this window.history.pushState('data', 'Title', 'index?a=recieved');

Comment: I don't know any other way. window.history.pushState it would be for other cases. When you want a url with history or a shortcut to section.